# using the variable passed in constructor in prototype function in javascript with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, constructor, prototype

I have several div with the same "album" class, so I wanted to create a class using constructor and prototype. Here's what I did

```
function Album(album){
    this.album = album;

    console.log(this.album === album)
    console.log($(this.album) === $(album))
}

Album.prototype = {
    init: function(){

    },

    loadImages: function(){

    }
};

$('.album').each(function(){    
    var album = new Album(this);
});
```

I need to access the album variable that I passed in to the class Album in the init function, so I have to store it in this.album. However I don't understand that why
console.log(this.album === album) is true but
console.log($(this.album) === $(album)) is false

I need to use jquery in prototype, is there other way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: `$(this.album).get(0) === $(album).get(0)` should also return true if `this.album === album` returns true. But each time you wrap a DOM element inside the jQuery notation (with `$`) you will get a new reference, like Alex Wayne explained below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('body') === $('body') // false
```

Basically, you are doing this right.  jQuery is screwing with you.

With objects the `===` operator is only true if it is the same object. In this case, jQuery makes a brand new object each time it wraps a DOM element, making a new object even if it's wrapping the same element it did a second ago.

Here's an example of why this is in plain JS, without jQuery:

```
var domEl = document.getElementById('whatev');
var a = { el: domEl };
var b = { el: domEl };

domEl === domEl // true
a === b         // false
```

Here there is 2 objects, both have identical data and wrap the same object. But they are different objects and therefore not `===` to each other.